# SQL Patch that will change all INT values to JSON

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: DB Table]

I have a table called `photoProcess`. There is a column within this table `photoProcess`.`storyId`.

Currently, all values within the `storyId` column are being stored as a single integer. I am changing the column type to VARCHAR so that I can store the values as JSON. My question is how I can write a MySQL patch that will change all `storyId` values of these values to a JSON string.

Example:
Original `photoProcess`.`storyId` value for the first row is 6649.
I'd like to change that value to ["6649"] and do so on a large scale for all others.

Comment: That sounds like a super bad idea. Normally references like that are indexed, which is not practical for a JSON column. Additionally that kind of schema violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql):

```
UPDATE photoProcess SET storyId = CONCAT('["', storyId , '"]')
```